# Is there a way to "console log"/ show the return type of a function that uses implicity return type resolution in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Given a function, like bellow I would like to know its return type. It's just for learning purposes, out of curiosity..

```
function teste(x:number){
    if(x < 10){
      return x;
    }
    return null
}
```

Comment: You can't really `console.log` it since types are erased at runtime. Depending on the editor you use, you should be able to hover over the function to see its return type.

Comment: If I get you clearly `typeof` could help you in this case. For example `typeof(10)` will return you `'number'`. So you can put any variable inside to get it's actual type.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code can tell you the return type when you hover over the function name (if you have the right typescript extensions installed).

In your case, the return type is: `number | null`